# XCode: Initializer element is not a compile-time constant

Tags: c, xcode, constants, compile-time-constant

I am writing a program in C using XCode. I don't use C much, usually I use C++. I've never used XCode before.

Compile error is quite simple, the following lines of code are not being treated as compile time constants by the compiler.

```
const double PI = 4.0 * atan(1.0);
const double TAU = 8.0 * atan(1.0);
```

I'm sure this is allowed in C++ 11, although I can't be certain, since I last used it some months ago.

My guess is that the XCode compiler / the C standard does not allow constants to be computed in this way.

Is there an alternative I can use? I don't much fancy the "define" alternative...

```
#define PI 4.0 * atan(1.0);
```

As this will (may?) cause unnecessary run-time overhead.

Comment: Why not use `M_PI` from `math.h` or just `3.141592653589`? That should be `double` precision.

Answer (score 3):

> the following lines of code are not being treated as compile time constants by the compiler.

The compiler is right, because they are not compile-time constants: they both make calls to the runtime portion of the Standard C library.

> I don't much fancy the "define" alternative...

That's right, `#define` is *not* an alternative, because it would force a constant to be re-evaluated in each expression that you have it.

> Is there an alternative I can use?

Sure - you can use `M_PI` for a definition of the `π` constant <sup>*</sup>, and `2*M_PI` for the `TAU`:

```
const double TAU = 2 * M_PI;
```

> I'm sure this is allowed in C++ 11

This is correct: unlike C, C++ does not requite initializers to be compile-time constants.

> How is it that calling `atan()` isn't allowed, but the mathematical operation `2 * M_PI` is allowed?

This is because the standard requires compilers to perform all numeric operations on constant expressions during the compile time. However, a single runtime call, such as `atan(...)`, will "poisons" the whole thing, so the compiler will evaluate as much as it can, but the expression will remain a runtime expression, not a compile-time constant.

<sup>*</sup> It is not standard, but many libraries define it anyway.

Comment: Why am I allowed to do this in C++? M_PI doesn't sound like a rigid solution... What is it, and how many digits of precision does it have?

Comment: Actually, another question: How is it that calling atan() isn't allowed, but the mathematical operation 2 * M_PI is allowed?

Answer (score 1):

This is not allowed in C.  Unlike C++, C requires global variables to be initialized by *compile-time* constants.  `atan(1.0)` is not a compile-time constant because it requires calling the function `atan()` at runtime.

The simple solution is don't call `atan()`, just us the actual numeric values of pi and tau as your initializers:

```
const double PI = 3.141592653589793;
const double TAU = 2*PI;
```

Some math libraries also provide the constant `M_PI` for you already, so you can just that:

```
const double PI = M_PI;
```

but that's not standard C (C89 or C99), so don't rely on all implementations having that constant.

Comment: Ah, so it is a language subtly. It would be really good if C2014 (does such a thing exist?) extended the language to allow this.